# Find the maximum value in a column for each partition

Tags: oracle, max, analytic-functions, partition-by

I have table structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test
( col1 NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  col2 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  col3 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  col4 VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

It has data:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
0         A      B       X
1         A      B       Y
2         A      B       Z
1         C      D       L
3         C      D       M
```

I need to find value of col4 which has maximum value for combination of col2 and col3. e.g. my result should be:

```
col4
  Z
  M
```

I tried to use oracle analytic function:

```
SELECT col4, MAX(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3) FROM (
SELECT col2, col3, col4, col1 
FROM new_test);
```

But it is not working as expected. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Update:
I could make it work using:

```
SELECT a.col4
FROM new_test a,
  (SELECT col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    MAX(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3) AS col1
  FROM new_test
  ) b
WHERE a.col2 = b.col2
AND a.col3   = b.col3
AND a.col4   = b.col4
AND a.col1   = b.col1;
```

Is there any better way than this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expect that result:

```
col4
  Z
  M
```

You should write:

```
SELECT MAX(col4) AS col4 FROM new_test GROUP BY col2,col3
```

This will return the maximum value found in column `col4` for each pair of `col2,col3`

---

If you need that:

```
COL2    COL3    COL4
A       B       Z
C       D       M
```

Write:

```
SELECT col2,col3,MAX(col4) AS col4 FROM new_test GROUP BY col2,col3
```

---

Finally, if you need:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
2       A       B       Z
3       C       D       M
```

There are many variations. Like this one:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 
  FROM new_test
  NATURAL JOIN (SELECT col2,col3,MAX(col4) AS col4 
                  FROM new_test GROUP BY col2,col3)
```

Comment: Dear Sylvain, thank you very much. Your query is quite easy to read compared to mine. But I observed that perfomrance of both queries is same. Is there any better/performant way?

Comment: @user613114 About performances: my first though would be to add a compound index on `col2,col3,col4`. But without knowing exactly your table structure ("keys") and the execution plan, it is hard to tell more. Feel free to _ask an other question_ for that!